# Proportionality to find spent years for price drop

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Well, the title's kinda messy, but this is a concrete example of what I'm trying to find out:

Lets say there is a price of 40.000 USD, if the price drops at half, **how many years does it take for the price to become 5 USD**?

I believe that this has something to do with proportionality. Am I mistaken? What' the solution to this?

Comment: It is often called *exponential decay*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the price drops in half each year, then starting at 40: $40\to20\to10\to5$, so it takes 3 years. Notice that this is repeated multiplication by $0.5$, i.e. $0.5^3\times40 = 5$

With larger numbers, and you may have meant starting at 40000 (I know some countries have different conventions for the decimal point), it's easier to write an equation:
$$\begin{align}
0.5^n\times40000 &= 5,\;\;\;\mbox{but $0.5 = 1/2$ and $(1/x)^n = x^{-n}$}\\
2^{-n}\times40000 &= 5,\;\;\;\mbox{take logs to base 2}\\
-n + \log_2 40000 &= \log_2 5\\
n &= \log_2 40000 - \log_2 5\\
&= 12.96578
\end{align}$$

So 13 years in round numbers.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I'm not really good at maths so I couldn't see the use of logarithms here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

3 years.  After one year the price is $\$20$. After two years the price is 10. Then after 3 years the price is $\$5$.

Comment: please note that a single dollar sign doesn't display a dollar. It's a shortcut for entering mathematics mode. So writing, e.g., \$x^y\$ will get you $x^y$. Hope this helps.